# With multiple sql order by clause, is all order bys run even if earlier order by has proved that the rows are not equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

In a SQL query with multiple `order by` clauses, is all of them really run during execution?

Example:

```
select * from my_table
order by field5, field3, field2
```

If the the list after execution of 'order by' field5 and field3 has a unique list whit only one combination of field5 and field3, is 'order by field2' still run during execution of SQL query? Or is, in my case SQL Server, smart enough to see this and skip the last step?

I'm asking because I am writing a stored procedure where I have a list where I'm most of the time only would need to order by to or three columns, but in some cases I would like to order by a last column if necessary, but this will be an alpha numeric sorting and this will slow down the query, so of course I would like to avoid it as much as possible...

Comment: You're micro-optimizing. Better a tiny bit of extra overhead by listing potentially unnecessary fields to order by v.s. the overhead of having to maintain multiple queries that list every possible variant of ordering.

Comment: Since the overall *result* is exactly as you've specified it (that examining the 1st two columns is sufficient to determine the row's position in the result set), you're unlikely to find *any* documentation on whether this particular optimization is or is not actually implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra column on the end of the sort will have a negligible impact on the speed of the query.

If you can, creating a compound index as previously suggested is probably not a bad idea:

```
create index my_index on my_table (field5, field3, field2);
```

I would be astounded if the internal sort implementation didn't make the optimization your talking about anyway, that's data structures and algorithms 101.

Be warned though, there are situations where an index here would make things worse, if you have large table churn on a table with many tuples for example, and if you have a table with few columns to start with, the optimizer will just do a full table scan anyway because it'd be faster.

Comment: Indexes are of course smart and great for optimasation of queries like mine.

Comment: But I was more in the philosofic corner on how the sql-server is implemented... If it would skip the last order by, then maybe indexing is unnecessary. Or is the recommendation of complexed indexes a hint that all sorting is executed any way?

Comment: I would postulate that unless that cardinality of the set of rows that were distinguished by field2 is high, the last column should be irrelevant as the database will retrieve data blocks not individual rows anyway and would therefore already have the information needed to finalize the sort.  Once you factor in isolation however, this may have bad side-effects that are hard to predict.  If the table needed to be referenced, a lock would likely be generated during sort to ensure consistency, so I'd go with the full index regardless of the simple algorithmic details for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely yes, I can't see how SQL Server would know if there are multiple rows for the last column other than actually reading them.

A better way to optimize this would be to add an index for the the columns you have in your `order by`, sorted in the same way.

Comment: The query is already reading the row in order to sort it.  Unless there are BLOBS or similar in the row, the whole is gonna be read anyway.